# Is there a way to use callback functions in joi validation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

Their Guru's

I'm doin a research on a code I saw on the internet, but if I see the syntax, they have used Hapi/Joi which is depricated.
My question is how can I use this syntax in Joi?

```
app.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {

const id = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9999999);

  Joi.validate(data, schema, (err, value) => {


    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json({
        status: 'error',
        message: 'Invalid request data',
        data: data
      });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        message: 'User created successfully',
        data: Object.assign({id}, value)
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspecting the types (`index.ds.ts`) file in [Github](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/66065372198ddd3ac20df3ba960caba8f6e70522/lib/index.d.ts) indeed there is no callback style `validate` function, only those two methods:

```js
        /**
         * Validates a value using the schema and options.
         */
        validate(value: any, options?: ValidationOptions): ValidationResult;

        /**
         * Validates a value using the schema and options.
         */
        validateAsync(value: any, options?: AsyncValidationOptions): Promise<any>;
```

However you can use `util.callbackify` - [callbackify examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-util-callbackify-method/) to transform `validateAsync` into a callback node style if you really want to:

```js
const Joi = require('joi');
const { callbackify } = require('util');

// A very simple data object
const obj = { a: 23 };

// A very simple joi schema which checks if schema is an object with the `a` property being a string
const schema = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.string(),
});

// Callback style (which i don't recommend since its not available in `joi` package)
callbackify(() => schema.validateAsync(obj))((err, ret) => {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      status: 'error',
      message: 'Invalid request data',
      data: data,
    });
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    message: 'User created successfully',
    data: Object.assign({ id }, value),
  });
});
```

I would use what `Joi` provide, as in the following 2 examples:

```js
// using async/await - you need to mark you controller as async, like:
// app.post('/test', async (req, res, next) => ...

try {
  await schema.validateAsync(obj);
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    message: 'User created successfully',
    data: Object.assign({ id }, value),
  });
} catch (err) {
  res.status(400).json({
    status: 'error',
    message: 'Invalid request data',
    data: data,
  });
}
```

Or even with just promises:

```js
schema
  .validateAsync(obj)
  .then(() =>
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      message: 'User created successfully',
      data: Object.assign({ id }, value),
    })
  )
  .catch(() =>
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 'error',
      message: 'Invalid request data',
      data: data,
    })
  );
```

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation @tam.teixeira, indeed I also recommend not to use the callbackify because it pollutes the code. my favorite option will be the first option but without the try catch because again it pollutes the code. Instead I will use a custom error handler middleware and let express take care of the particular error.